# How to batch the app events with max of 1000 events per second when using Splunk HTTP Event Collector (HEC)

Tags: splunk, splunk-sdk, splunk-hec

I need to send the batched events to Splunk HTTP Event Collector, say 1000 events per second.

Below is the example of 5 log events that are sent to Splunk HEC -

```
% curl "https://splunk-example.com:8088/services/collector/raw?channel=093DCD-BC98-8UET-8AFE-8413C3825C4C&sourcetype=test_type&index=test_index"
-H "Authorization: Splunk ******-****-****-****-*********" -d '<log line 1>   <log line 2>  <log line 3>  <log line 4>

  Output:  {"text":"Success","code":0}%
```

So how do I configure to send the application logs as 1000 events/seconds to Splunk HEC?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do your sourcetype's props.conf and transforms.conf files look like?

Comment: What "application" are you trying to configure to send to HEC?

Answer (score 0):

In your `props.conf` file for the `sourcetype` you should use `"SHOULD_LINEMERGE = false"`. That'll break each log line into separate events.

Now, what if your event is multi line?

Then this document should help: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/Data/Configureeventlinebreaking

Comment: how does linebreaking have anything to do with how many events are sent per second to the HEC?

Comment: THe original question was unclear, fair point. My assumption was that there was an issue with splunk receiving multiple logs per second. Personally, I send thousands of logs per second to my indexers (large network syslog) with no special config whatsoever. Except for the line merging.

Comment: don't assume: ask for clarifying information. SO isn't like "traditional" internet forums. The expectation is that it's a question and answer format, not a "stop some semi-/un-helpful comment and run" site :)

Comment: Also - OP specifically asked about *batching* sending logs to HEC, not *merely* how many events could they send per second: they want to know how to send up to 1000 events at a time in a batch per second :)

Answer (score 0):

The send rate configuration i.e throttling should be done on the client side.
I would assume that you will not be using "plain" curl, but rather it will be some sort of script/application. So your throttling needs to be done there.